# PostgreSQL Insert into table with subquery selecting from multiple other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I am learning SQL (postgres) and am trying to insert a record into a table that references records from two other tables, as foreign keys.

Below is the syntax I am using for creating the tables and records:

```
-- Create a person table + insert single row
CREATE TABLE person (
    pname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (pname)
);
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('personOne');

-- Create a city table + insert single row
CREATE TABLE city (
    cname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (cname)
);
INSERT INTO city VALUES ('cityOne');

-- Create a employee table w/ForeignKey reference
CREATE TABLE employee (
    ename VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES person(pname) NOT NULL,
    ecity VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES city(cname) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ename, ecity)
);

-- create employee entry referencing existing records
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(
    SELECT pname FROM person
        WHERE pname='personOne' AND  <-- ISSUE
    SELECT cname FROM city
        WHERE cname='cityOne
);
```

Notice in the last block of code, where I'm doing an `INSERT` into the employee table, I don't know how to string together multiple `SELECT` sub-queries to get both the existing records from the person and city table such that I can create a new employee entry with attributes as such:

`ename='personOne'`
`ecity='cityOne'`

The textbook I have for class doesn't dive into sub-queries like this and I can't find any examples similar enough to mine such that I can understand how to adapt them for this use case.

Insight will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to do this then this can be done by selecting from both tables, but as you are learning, so suggesting that this is not a good database design.  The query can be 'SELECT pname,cname FROM person, city WHERE pname='personOne' AND  cname='cityOne' but this will not give correct data as directly there is no relationship between person and city table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn’t appear to be any obvious relationship between city and person which will make your life hard

The general pattern for turning a select that has two base tables giving info, into an insert is:

```
INSERT INTO table(column,list,here)
SELECT column,list,here 
FROM
  a 
  JOIN b ON a.x = b.y
```

In your case there isn’t really anything to join *on* because your one-column tables have no column in common. Provide eg a `cityname` in Person (because it seems more likely that one city has many person) then you can do

```
INSERT INTO employee(personname,cityname)
SELECT p.pname, c.cname  
FROM
  person p
  JOIN city c ON p.cityname = c.cname
```

But even then, the tables are related between themselves and don’t need the third table so it’s perhaps something of an academic exercise only, not something you’d do in the real world

If you just want to mix every person with every city you can do:

```
INSERT INTO employee(personname,cityname)
SELECT pname, cname 
FROM
  person p
  CROSS JOIN city c
```

But be warned, two people and two cities will cause 4 rows to be inserted, and so on (20 people and 40 cities, 800 rows. Fairly useless imho)

However, I trust that the general pattern shown first will suffice for your learning; write a SELECT that shows the data you want to insert, then simply write `INSERT INTO table(columns)` above it. The number of columns inserted to must match the number of columns selected. Don’t forget that you can select fixed values if no column from the query has the info (`INSERT INTO X(p,c,age) SELECT personname, cityname, 23 FROM ...`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough answer. You're correct that this was a purely academic exercise and, as such, likely wasn't practical. As it turns out, I was over-zealous in my assumption that the foreign keys would need to be queried. The assignment provided the tables pre-populated. Thanks for helping me learn something anyway!

Answer (score -1):

The following will work for you:

```
INSERT INTO employee
SELECT pname, cname FROM person, city
WHERE pname='personOne' AND cname='cityOne';
```

This is a `cross join` producing a cartesian product of the two tables (since there is nothing to link the two).  It reads slightly oddly, given that you could just as easily have inserted the values directly. But I assume this is because it is a learning exercise.

Please note that there is a typo in your create employee.  You are missing a comma before the primary key.